# .refundRequestSheet not working correctly in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, in-app-purchase, subscription

I'd like to use the `.refundRequestSheet` method for refunding by the user in my app. It's not working correctly.

There are problems here.

How can I catch the result of user's action for refunding?
There is [request refund] button and nothing happens when I tap it and it always returns `.userCancelled` after the refund view disappears.

```
.refundRequestSheet(
    for: selectedTransactionID ?? 0,
    isPresented: $refundSheetIsPresented
) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let status):
        switch status {
        case .success:
            log(" success")
        case .userCancelled:
            log(" userCancelled")
        @unknown default:
            log(" default")
        }
    case .failure(let error):
        log(error)
    }
}
```

After requesting a refund and then requesting a refund again, the refund view appears. But the message is "you've already requested a refund for this purchase" and there is a button to close the view, Done button.
It's not clickable in the refund view.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this:

```
@State private var refundSheetIsPresented = false

// ...

Button("Request Refund") {
    refundSheetIsPresented = true // Show the refund view
}
.sheet(isPresented: $refundSheetIsPresented, content: {
    refundRequestSheet(
        for: selectedTransactionID ?? 0,
        isPresented: $refundSheetIsPresented
    ) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let status):
            switch status {
            case .success:
                log("Refund success")
            case .userCancelled:
                log("Refund userCancelled")
            @unknown default:
                log("Refund default")
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            log(error)
        }
    }
})
```